# Clojure Agent Parellel HTTP IllegalStateException and await-for

Tags: clojure, urlconnection, agent, illegalstateexception

I am working through the example of making parallel http requests in Clojure,

http://lethain.com/a-couple-of-clojure-agent-examples/

In particular

```
(ns parallel-fetch
  (:import [java.io InputStream InputStreamReader BufferedReader]
           [java.net URL HttpURLConnection]))

(defn get-url [url]
  (let [conn (.openConnection (URL. url))]
    (.setRequestMethod conn "GET")
    (.connect conn)
    (with-open [stream (BufferedReader.
                       (InputStreamReader. (.getInputStream conn)))]
      (.toString (reduce #(.append %1 %2)
                          (StringBuffer.) (line-seq stream))))))

(defn get-urls [urls]
  (let [agents (doall (map #(agent %) urls))]
    (doseq [agent agents] (send-off agent get-url))
    (apply await-for 5000 agents)
    (doall (map #(deref %) agents))))

(prn (get-urls '("http://lethain.com" "http://willarson.com")))
```

When I run this in the

```
IllegalStateException await-for in transaction
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Weird... I just tried the code and I don't get the `IllegalStateException ` exception. The error message comes from the defintion for [`await-for`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/await-for), but it only should show up when that function is used inside a transaction (i.e. inside a `dosync`), since that's what the `io!` macro is for and I'm not seeing a single transaction in your code.

Comment: Could you double check that you haven't accidentally typed `doseq` as `dosync` in `get-urls` while also moving the final closing paren of the `doseq` form so as to include the `(apply await-for ...)` in its body?

Comment: Yep, double checked.  I'm getting this error when I put the code in a .clj file and then try to load it from the repl:

`(use 'parallel-fetch :reload-all)
IllegalStateException await-for in transaction  clojure.core/await-for (core.clj:2942)`

Comment: What if you comment out the `(prn (get-urls '("http://lethain.com" "http://willarson.com")))`, load the code through `(use 'parallel-fetch :reload-all)` and then execute the `(prn ,,,)` from the REPL? My guess is that `use` is loading the code inside a transaction that the `await-for` is executed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the comment on the question into account:

A transaction is being set up in the process of loading your namespace, and since it has a call to `get-urls` at the top-level, the `await-for` happens in that transaction and throws the exception.

The best way to fix that is to put the `prn / get-urls` form inside a function and only call it once the namespace is loaded. (If you wanted to run this code as a standalone app, with `lein run` or `java -jar` on an überjar, you'd put a call to that function inside `-main`.)

Incidentally, the transaction is set up when you use `:reload-all`, but not without it. (See the private functions `load-lib`, which checks for the presence of `:reload-all` and decides to use the private function `load-all` if it's there, and `load-all` itself, which is where the transaction is set up. [Here's a link to the 1.5.1 source.](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.5.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5344))